# Injecting random variable into every View in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am just getting started with Laravel and working on porting a mess of a site to the framework.

One feature of the site is a dynamically added image in the header. I am using a common Blade template and was wondering if there is any way to inject a random variable (an integer between 1 and 4 would do) into every View that uses that layout.

What I would like to do is to be able to add something like so in the the common template-

`<img src="img/cutouts/cutout-<?= $randomInt;?>.jpg" alt=""/>`

with `$randomInt` sent to every View

Comment: Found that I can do this - `<?= HTML::image('img/cutouts/cutout-'.rand(1,4).'.png', '', array('id'=> 'headerImage'));?>`, acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look into [View composers](http://laravel.com/docs/views#view-composers)

So you would have something like:

```
View::composer('your.view', function($view)
{
    $view->with('randomInt', rand(1,4));
}
```

That will pass the $randomInt variable in everytime you use the 'your.view' (or whatever) View.

Comment: I knew I was forgetting a feature somewhere in there. Both this and the solution in my comment do basically the same thing but this is critical knowledge for more advanced things.. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible to add a variable to all views through `View::share()`.

For example, you could modify the `__construct` method in `Base_Controller` with:

```
View::share('randomInt', rand(1,4));
```